# No delimiting whitespaces in source code generated by knitr in case of unicode variable characters (greek)

Tags: r, unicode, latex, knitr, tex

I have tried to type variables in R code with LaTeX textgreek and knitr.

The problem is in source code formatting.
There are no delimiting whitespaces in case of greek. [image]

You see?

The source Rnw:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
α <- 1
β <- 2
γ <- α + β 
α
β
γ
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
d <- a + b + c 
a
@

\end{document}
```

And that is generated tex:[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm confused, what exactly is the problem? What is the encoding used for your source file? A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Pictures of code aren't as nice because then we have to retype it all to see what's going on.

Comment: @MrFlick I've edited my question. The problem is in source code formatting. I've provided a link to my source at GitHub. Hope that will be good.

Comment: It's better to create a minimal example required to reproduce the problem and include it in the question itself. External links to code that may disappear over time is discouraged.

Comment: @MrFlick, I've edited my question appropriately.

Comment: FYI, this bug in base R is said to be fixed in R 3.4.1, which was just released a few hours ago: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2017/000616.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug of base R, and I have filed a report to https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17254

Before it is fixed in base R, your only choice is to turn off syntax highlighting (or avoid multibyte characters in object names):

```
<<highlight=FALSE>>=
```